# Where is the Bonjour COM library?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sdk, bonjour

I've downloaded and installed the [Bonjour SDK for Windows](http://developer.apple.com/bonjour) on my Win7 64bit machine.

I've tried to build both of the the projects in C:\Program Files\Bonjour SDK\Samples\CS.  However they both reference Bonjour, causing me to get the following build error 'Cannot load type library for reference "Bonjour". Library not registered.'

Bonjour appears to be installed properly as I can run the Bonjour Printer Wizard and it appears to work properly.

Any idea why Visual Studio can't find the Library?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep ! Bonjour is only a **32 Bit Control** and only accessible from a **32 Bit application**.

Please try compiling a test-application from a 32-bit-machine with 32 bit target.

Comment: Thanks! Even though the 2.0 SDK claims "The Bonjour SDK contains header files, libraries, executables, installers, and sample code for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows." This doesn't seem to be true for .NET.

Comment: they may have included a 64-Bit-Dll, but I dont know where that could be. and you must register that with regsvr64 ?

Comment: I think I'll give Mono.Zeroconf a try instead of the apple SDK.